# Positioning 2 CSS lists correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a horizontal project list, the projects name are up and their images are under it.
like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty3mU.png

Most of the work is already done and it's already working, but I'm having two problems.

1- Since I created two list, one for the names and of the images I'm unable to positions 
them correctly under each other.

2- the list that contains the images is not starting correctly.

Here's a working JsFiddler http://jsfiddle.net/P3SJ3/1/ .

```
<ul id = "top" class="horizontal-slide ">
    <li class="span2 animate-repeat borderlist" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" > <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <div class="text-block vertical-text ">{{item.name}}</div>
    </a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="bottom" class="horizontal-slide ">
<li class="span2 animate-repeat  borderlist image-block " ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" >
    <ul class="  ">
    <li class=" " ng-repeat="url in item.urls | filter:search" > 
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <img src="{{url.url}}" alt="" />
            </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

```
ul.horizontal-slide {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;

}

ul.horizontal-slide li[class*="span"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

ul.horizontal-slide li[class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.text-block {
    width:30px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left : 20px;
}

.image-block {
    width:50px;
}

.image-block ul {
    list-style-type: none;     
}

.image-block ul li {
    float:right;   
}

.borderlist {
    list-style-position:inside;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Dude, you want to make that fiddle a little more user friendly...cut it down to a **limited** example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` in **ul.horizontal-slide li[class*="span"]** as mentioned below:

```
ul.horizontal-slide li[class*="span"] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3SJ3/2/) here

**Update** :

Also you have to manage inside css of the **TOP** ul. Have a look at update [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3SJ3/2/)

Comment: Scroll to the end in the fidller , you will notice that the first list finishes before the second. They're not totally synced.

Comment: @NarJhanam: Have a look at my updated Answer and fiddle. Don't forget to mark it as an answer. Have a great day

Comment: Thank you a lot, this indeed did it, but please fix the JSFiddle link to this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3SJ3/12/).